# Oracle Forms Runtime error

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

When I am running a form in Forms 11g

```
http://rahulsingh-pc:8888/forms/frmservlet
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Failure of server APACHE bridge:
No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds or idempotent set to OFF.
```

Products installed:

1. Web Logic 10.3.5
2. forms&reports&portals 11.1.2.0

Can anybody help me fix this problem?

Comment: Sorry for providing you with very little information.As a newbie I have very little idea about the Oracle Forms.So could you tell me how to check the log files for the Oracle Forms Output?

Comment: Here is the Database Config

    Enterprise Manager Database Control URL - (orcl) :
http://RahulSingh-PC:1158/em

Your database configuration files have been installed in
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0

while other components selected for installation have been installed in
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1.

Be cautious not to accidentally delete these configuration files.

The iSQL*Plus URL is:
http://RahulSingh-PC:5560/isqlplus

The iSQL*Plus DBA URL is:
http://RahulSingh-PC:5560/isqlplus/dba

Comment: And here is the Forms Config:
'Oracle Home Location: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_FRHome1
Oracle Instance Location: C:\Oracle\Middleware\asinst_1
Domain Option: Create Domain
Domain Name: ClassicDomain
Domain Home: C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain
Domain Port No: 7001
User Name: weblogic
Automatic Port Detection: true
Administrator Console: http://RahulSingh-PC:7001/console
EM Console: http://RahulSingh-PC:7001/em
EMAgent URL: http://RahulSingh-PC:5155/emd/main
Forms URL: http://RahulSingh-PC:8888/forms/frmservlet
Reports URL: http://RahulSingh-PC:8888/reports/rwservlet'

Answer (score 1):

This is Weblogic. The FORMS services are actually answered by a Weblogic Java Server. It is named WLS_FORMS and you can start it via the web logic management console (available by default as `http://localhost:7001/console`).

Click on the servers link on the left, then on the main pane, select "Control" tab. Select the checkbox next to WLS_FORMS and select "Start listening".

Comment: Even though the AdminServer is running, the other servers (WLS_FORMS, WLS_REPORTS, etc) are not started by default. You can correct this with batch scripts, or following the Oracle supports notes on creating Windows services for these items.